# Short circuit with male-2-male usb cable

Tags: usb-power, alternative-power

My RPi 2B constantly sensed voltage drops on my 2 A charger.

Since I know that I can additionally use one of those old [USB Y-cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-cable#USB) from external disk drives to support the power rail on my RPi 3B (RPi USB to second charging port), I took a male-male USB cable and hooked it to the second charging port.

The RPi pretty much directly produced a cloud of magic smoke. What might have happened here?

Comment: A "a male-male USB cable" is a travesty which is not supported by any USB standard, There is NO "second charging port"

Comment: @Milliways I wrote "RPi USB _to_ second charging port" (of the charger), not _of_. Did you have a look at the link above? It's quite clear that it's not standard conform since the Y-cables themselves are not ([compare](https://superuser.com/a/1022770/383800)). But that does not touch the question.

Comment: What you did is **not** equivalent to a USB Y-cable.  The double end of a USB-Y cable is connected to *one* voltage source through two pathways to increase the available current, since those pathways are regulated (eg. USB 2.0 is supposed to be 500 mA).  You connected one device to two separate voltage sources.  The equivalent would be taking a Y-cable, plugging the one end into a disk drive, and the two ends of the Y into *two different* USB hubs.

Answer (score 1):

The "magic smoke" is released when you connect significantly more than 5V to the Pi.  Anything over 5.5V would be risky.  Anything over 5.25V is not recommended.

Comment: I used a working 2-port USB charger. So the voltage is not the issue. Rather that apparent short circuits. Furthermore, magic smoke is created by current, not voltage (but over-voltage certainly may lead to increased current).

Comment: Voltage is relative (unlike say, temperature) because there is often no *common ground.*  You hooked the Pi up to two different DC voltage sources that perhaps did not share a common ground.  Meaning any difference between them would cause a current draw on the lower one (ie., like a short circuit, a path for irresistible amounts of current to flow).   I'm not much with electricity so you can double check that, eg., ask on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
what the downside of connecting two separate 5V DC supplies together this way is.